# Multiply Columns from Multiple DataFrames, Keeping Non-Overlapping Columns, and Creating New DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have two dataframes as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = {'B36': {'A44': 0.218, 'A45': 0.062, 'A46': 0.035,  'plt': 0.450, 'rs': 0.878},
        'B43': {'A44': 0.018, 'A45': 0.427, 'A46': 0.100, 'plt': 0.450, 'rs': 0.878}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1

df2 = {'lID':  [26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
       'lCTY': [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18],
       'A44':[77, 37, 51, 55, 57, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       'A45':[77, 37, 51, 55, 57, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
       'A46':[78, 36, 49, 53, 50, 99, 99, 99, 10, 99]
       }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2
```

What I want to do is multiply rows in df1 with similarly-named columns in df2. I want to do this for each column in df1
and output these as separate dataframes. Additionally, I want to keep the non-overlapping rows/columns in both df1 and df2.

My attempt at doing both is shown below. What I was hoping for was a more concise way of going about this.

```
df1_index = set(df1.index)
df2_cols = set(df2.columns)
col = list(df1_index.intersection(df2_cols))

# multiply df1 B36 items with df2 columns
df2[col] = df1['B36'][col].mul(df2[col], axis=0, fill_value=1)
df2['rs'] = df1.loc['rs'][0]
df2['plt'] = df1.loc['plt'][0]
df2

# multiply df1 B43 items with df2 columns
df2[col] = df1['B43'][col].mul(df2[col], axis=0, fill_value=1)
df2['rs'] = df1.loc['rs'][0]
df2['plt'] = df1.loc['plt'][0]
df2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to melt the column before multiplying; I'd like to think that your step may be more efficient (tests are a sure way to confirm/refute):

```py
# melt df2:
# keeping the index helps ensure unique index
# which we need later when unstacking
(df2
.melt(["lID", "lCTY"], ignore_index = False)
.set_index(["variable", "lID", "lCTY"], append = True)
 # move variable to level 0, so we can use it for multiplying
.reorder_levels(['variable', 'lID', 'lCTY', None])
.value # not really necessary to convert to a series here
# multiply independently, since the index is df1 is unique
# easier this way
.mul(df1.B36, level=0)
.mul(df1.B43, level=0)
.unstack('variable')
# sorting can be ignored if it is not that important
.sort_index(level = -1)
# assign the remaining rows that do not match
.assign(rs=df1.at["rs", "B36"], plt=df1.at["plt", "B36"])
.rename_axis(columns = None)
.reset_index(level = ['lID', 'lCTY'])
)

   lID  lCTY       A44       A45     A46     rs   plt
0   26    18  0.302148  2.038498  0.2730  0.878  0.45
1   26    18  0.145188  0.979538  0.1260  0.878  0.45
2   26    18  0.200124  1.350174  0.1715  0.878  0.45
3   26    18  0.215820  1.456070  0.1855  0.878  0.45
4   26    18  0.223668  1.509018  0.1750  0.878  0.45
5   12    18  0.039240  0.264740  0.3465  0.878  0.45
6   12    18  0.039240  0.264740  0.3465  0.878  0.45
7   12    18  0.039240  0.264740  0.3465  0.878  0.45
8   12    18  0.039240  0.264740  0.0350  0.878  0.45
9   12    18  0.039240  0.264740  0.3465  0.878  0.45
```

This matches the example shared; depending on the complexity, you may have to break it up, put into separate variables and recombine, or use the `pipe` method (i prefer the first, as `pipe` , when combined with anonymous functions can lead to incomprehensible code)

Answer (score 0):

@ sammywemmy, based on your answer I used the following steps which I think works well for what I want to do.

*1. the multiplication code*

this code excludes all non-similar indices/columns from df1 and df2

```
d1idx = set(df1.index)
d2cols = set(df2.columns)
col = list(d1idx.intersection(d2cols))

collt = []
for idx, colname in enumerate(df1, start=1):
    collt.append(df1[colname][col].mul(df2[col], axis=0, fill_value=1))
print(collt)
```

*2. collect non-similar indices/columns from df1 and df2*

this combines the non-similar indices/columns from df1 and df2.  I chose to use  use `df.iloc[:,][0]`, instead of `df.at[]` because the variable name at that index might change, so this approach makes it a bit easier.

```
d2 = df2.loc[:, ['lID', 'lCTY']]
d2 = d2.join(pd.DataFrame({'plt': df1.loc['plt'][0], 
                           'rs': df1.loc['rs'][0]}, index=d2.index))

print(d2)
```

*3. merge non-similar columns into the multiplied dataframe*

finally, add the non-similar columns back into the dataframe

```
lstdf = {}
for idx, dif in enumerate(collt, start=1):
    lstdf[idx] = dif.merge(d2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(lstdf)
```